# How to set key value in CGrideView when grid is populated from table-view

Tags: mysql, gridview, yii

In Yii CGridView, when we select any row from grid by using:

> 'selectionChanged' => "function(id){ $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id) }",

it gives proper key value of the record **(when the grid is populated by table)**

---

But, when I populate Grid with data of 3 tables as a **View.** The key value returns undefined.

I have **id** as field, and I want it as **key** value in that particular view. So, I can get Id of particular row to proceed further.

p.s.:
All the 3 tables have their own Primary Key.

Comment: how do you populated the grid, using any data provider?

Comment: yes using data provider, Actually all are same except Model. Model is generated with reference to database view rather than database table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into these options?

[KeyAttribute (CActiveDataProvider)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider#keyAttribute-detail)

[KeyField (CArrayDataProvider)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider#keyField-detail)

They are what is used to generate that id in a gridview

Comment: No, i didn't looked at those.. will try it and reply you. As for now, I have done it with js by fetching first cell of each row as keyfield

Comment: did this end up working for you?  If so, I'd appreciate having my answer accepted :-)  gives you a better reputation and increases mine as well