# How to assign unique id attribute to each table row of a CGridView?

Tags: yii, cgridview

I am attempting to assign a unique id to each table row in Yii's `CGridView`.

Preferably something like `$data->id` from the database table.

I have been unsuccessful at adding an `id` attribute to each rendered `<tr>`.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

CGridView have an option called 'rowHtmlOptionsExpression' , you can declare like the followings to assign row an id

```
'rowHtmlOptionsExpression' => 'array("id"=>$data->id)',
```

It's better than hacking into 'rowCssClassExpression'

Good luck !

Answer (score 4):

### Modern solution (since Yii 1.1.13)

This is now possible to do using the [`rowHtmlOptionsExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#rowHtmlOptionsExpression-detail) attribute, which allows assigning arbitrary HTML attributes to each rendered table row. For example:

```
'rowHtmlOptionsExpression' => '["id" => $data->id]'
```

### Original answer (earlier versions)

Not directly possible because `CGridView` does not support it, but there are a couple of straightforward solutions that you can try.

#### Subclass CGridView (good)

Simply create your own class `MyGridView extends CGridView` and override the `renderTableRow` method to spit out ids on every row. Have a look at [the stock implementation](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php#501), which does for the `class` attribute exactly what you 'd like to do for the `id` attribute.

#### Use a CSS class instead (not so good)

Speaking of `class` attributes, the `rowCssClassExpression` property can be used to dynamically generate classes out of the box. IMHO this is a bad workaround, but it's there.

Comment: You don't need to subclass CgridView, as said by Chung (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18711448/1396839) you can use rowHtmlOptionsExpression to pass attributes to the TR tag of the table. Furthermore, you can pass an array with many attributes, not only the id.

Comment: @alwar: That's true today, but it was not at the time I authored this answer -- `rowHtmlOptionsExpression` was only [added in Yii version 1.1.13](http://www.yiiframework.com/files/CHANGELOG-1.1.13.txt). I am updating the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend CGridView to add that functionality.

or be a bit hacky with rowCssClassExpression.

```
'rowCssClassExpression' => '\'" data-id="\' . $data->rowID'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the information I posted here:
[How to set key value in CGrideView when grid is populated from table-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818059/how-to-set-key-value-in-cgrideview-when-grid-is-populated-from-table-view/9962204#9962204)

In essence, as long as your dataprovider to the CGridview provides the data->id in a form that it understands, it will auto handle the $data->id stuff for you automatically so that it's easily available to javascript.

Answer (score -1):

`CGridView.rowHtmlOptionsExpression` is undefined

I don't think that we can use `rowHtmlOptionsExpression`