# Yii, Generate unquie ids one each tr element of CGridView

Tags: php, html, activerecord, yii

I have a CDbActiveRecord setup and I have a instance of the CGridView class setup as a widget.

Basically my end game is I need a table, but each row to contain the primary key of the row associated with the Active Record.

Such as:

```
<tr id="123"> <td> Column value 1 </td> <td> Col 2 </td> <td> Col 3 </td> </tr>
```

That's the specific of the row that I'm looking for.

Here's the code I've got so far to produce a table. (The json variable is set because this is inside a controller and the widget is returned as json.)

```
// get the content id for the version list
$contentID_v = Yii::app()->request->getParam("id"); 

// setup the criteria to fetch related items 
$versionCdbCriteria = new CDbCriteria;
$versionCdbCriteria->compare("contentID",$contentID_v); 

// setting up the active data provider for the version 
$vActiveDP = new CActiveDataProvider("FactsheetcontentVersion", array(
    "criteria" => $versionCdbCriteria,
    'pagination' => array('PageSize' => $this->paginationSize),
    'keyAttribute'=>'vID',
));

$json_data .= $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $vActiveDP,
        'columns' => array(
        'title',
        'created',
        'createdBy'
        ),
    'showTableOnEmpty' => 'false', 
),true);
```

This is what it produces for my active record.

```
 <div class="grid-view" id="yw0">
<div class="summary">Displaying 1-1 of 1 result(s).</div>
<table class="items"><thead>
    <tr><th id="yw0_c0">Factsheettitle</th>
        <th id="yw0_c1"><a href="jq/work/admin/index.php?r=factsheetManager/Editor
        &amp;id=25601&amp;getV=true&amp;_=1341694154760&amp;FactsheetcontentVersion_sort=created">Created</a>
        </th>
        <th id="yw0_c2"><a href="jq/work/admin/index.php?r=factsheetManager/
        Editor&amp;id=25601&amp;getV=true&amp;_=1341694154760&amp;FactsheetcontentVersion_sort=createdBy">Created By</a>
        </th>
    </tr></thead>
<tbody><tr class="odd"><td>Distribution</td><td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td><td>NULL</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
<div title="jq/work/admin/index.php?r=factsheetManager/Editor&amp;id=12&amp;id=25601&amp;getV=true&amp;_=1341694154760" style="display:none" class="keys"><span>8</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found a hack solution that works for now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11096827

Comment: its not exactly what you want, for that you'll have to extend CGridView. why exactly do you need unique row ids? there could be some other workaround..

Answer (score 1):

Just learning Yii myself, but this ones seems obvious?
Extend the widget like so.

```
    Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView');

    class MyGridView extends CGridView {
    //This does depend on your data structure
    $data=$this->dataProvider->data[$row];
    $id = $data['id']; //(This may be an object I have not checked is so: $data->id)

        public function renderTableRow($row)
        {
            if($this->rowCssClassExpression!==null)
            {
echo '<tr id="'.$id.'" class="'.$this->evaluateExpression($this->rowCssClassExpression,array('row'=>$row,'data'=>$data)).'">';
            }
            else if(is_array($this->rowCssClass) && ($n=count($this->rowCssClass))>0)
                echo '<tr id="'.$id.'"  class="'.$this->rowCssClass[$row%$n].'">';
            else
                echo '<tr id="'.$id.'" >';
            foreach($this->columns as $column)
                $column->renderDataCell($row);
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }

    }
```

Now to use this:

```
$json_data .= $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.MyGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $vActiveDP,
        'columns' => array(
        'title',
        'created',
        'createdBy'
        ),
    'showTableOnEmpty' => 'false', 
),true)
```

I am not familiar with YII yet, but you may have to register this as an extension and add it to your extensions dir... or perhaps its more of a component, I am not clear with regards to exactly where you place the code for overriding existing widgets, once I know I will edit this answer.